# Where do I submit a .desktop file updated with the Unity Launcher API?

Tags: unity, 11.04, development, chromium

Specifically, I decided to update the desktop file for Google Chrome to add a static quicklist (like is already present in Windows 7). Where do I have to submit it for inclusion in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

You should file a bug report with the feature request, you can file a bug report for chrome by opening a terminal and executing:

```
ubuntu-bug chromium-browser
```